# Permanent read access to a user's Facebook stream since offline_access was deprecated?

Tags: facebook, oauth, access-token, facebook-oauth

I had an idea for an app that would periodically access peoples' Facebook data. However, Facebook just deprecated the offline_access permission which prevents tokens expiring in a set time period.

Is there any way now for a 3rd party app to have continuous access to people's Facebook data (if they opt in, of course)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope, Facebook wants your user to visit and interact with your app every 60 days.  If your app is soooo bad that the user doesn't come back to it, Facebook doesn't really want your app to have access for indefinite time. So be a cool app and do something with it that has the user coming back periodically (before the 60 day limit) so you can get a fresh 60 day token.  Happy coding!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My app idea is similar to a credit score monitoring service. A good credit score monitoring service doesn't make me login periodically--it just works. I don't want my users to expend more effort than necessary. I'm not sure if 60 day tokens are okay.

Comment: I would image the only way around the new Facebook-imposed limitation would be to become a Facebook app partner. You should have your company's business development team contact Facebook to see if a partnership can be reached.

Answer (score 1):

Facebook hates its developers and likes to constantly break things for them, such as this recent disabling of offline_access. Unfortunately there is no replacement.  You could prompt for email permissions and email the user to let them know before the token expires that Facebook sucks and requires them to reauthenticate with your app to extend the token.